# Appending in middle of text in column data oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to append the text in middle of text .

1 EX :existing text is : `"Monoclonal Anti-FLAG, Clone 6F7"`

Result :`"<HIDE>Monoclonal Anti-<HIDE>FLAG, Clone 6F7"`.

2 EX :existing text is : `"Anti-100-KD subunit"`

Result  : `"<HIDE> Anti-</HIDE>100-KD subunit"`

I want to append `<HIDE>` tag where ever Anti and Monoclonal term is coming.

```
select * from table where regexp_like(colnanme, '^(Monoclonal Anti|Anti)')
```

Can you suggest how should i write this .for select i have written query .

Comment: What do you mean by "append" - do you need to append in a SELECT query, for further processing, or do you need to UPDATE the data in your existing table?

Comment: No append was meant for update statement.but i got the idea was unleashed was suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The predicted certain regular expression solution.

```
-- Start test data
with test_data as
    (select 'Monoclonal Anti-FLAG, Clone 6F7' as test_string from dual union all
     select 'Anti-100-KD subunit' from dual)
-- End test data     
select test_string,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(test_string,'(Monoclonal Anti-|Anti-)','<HIDE>\1</HIDE>')
from   test_data;


"TEST_STRING"                     "Result"
"Monoclonal Anti-FLAG, Clone 6F7" "<HIDE>Monoclonal Anti-</HIDE>FLAG, Clone 6F7"
"Anti-100-KD subunit"             "<HIDE>Anti-</HIDE>100-KD subunit"
```

Comment: Thanks @unleashed. your answer, your suggestion was very close to what my requirement was .

Answer (score 1):

you could use replace and like

```
 select replace(colname, 'Anti', '"<HIDE> Anti-</HIDE> ) 
 from table where colname like '%Anti%'
 and colname not like 'Monoclonal Anti%';
```

of for a combined situation you can use  a case when for lead replace

```
  select case when  colname like '%Monoclonal Anti%'  
                then replace(colname, 'Monoclonal Anti', '"<HIDE> Monoclonal Anti-</HIDE> ) 
              when  colname like '%Anti%'  
                 then replace(colname, 'Anti', '"<HIDE> Anti-</HIDE> ) 
               else colname
              end 
 from table where colname like '%Anti%';
```

Comment: you mean that you have both  'Anti'  and 'Monoclonal Anti' ??  answer  updated

Comment: yes right i have both ( Monoclonal Anti|Anti ) in query

Comment: Thanks but i have to update the query for both terms in a single query.

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar - there will almost certainly be other solutions proposed using regular expressions. Please note that this solution (by scaisEdge), while more complicated, is likely to be faster because it avoids regular expressions. It definitely gets my vote.

Comment: I would also note, if the OP needs to return all the rows, not just those that contain the substring `Anti-`, then the `where` condition wouldn't be needed, but there would need to be an `else colname` added to the `CASE` expression.

Comment: @mathguy   . yes  correct for else  but  .. is not  clear by OP what he really need

Comment: Thanks @mathguy  for your speedy response.and help.

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar  ..    I don't see the green mark ..  .. below the up/down  rating arrow ..

Comment: sorry i still i was not knowing that

Comment: @AnimeshSheolikar   .. OK i see that you have preferred  the answer from  unleashed ..  ..